# laravel 5.4 select2 multiple edit

Tags: jquery-select2, laravel-5.4

I don't know how to populate the edit function my select2 form. Here's my attempt on doing it. Controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $company = Company::find($id);      

    $categories = MainCategory::all();
    $categories2 = array();
        foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $categories2[$category->main_cat_id] = $category->main_cat_name;
    }

    return view('company/edit_company')->with('company', $company)->with('categories', $categories2);
}
```

here's my view:

```
<select class="form-control select2-multi" name="company_main_cat[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 50%" data-placeholder="select main category">
<option value='{{$category->main_cat_id}}'>{{$category->main_cat_name}}</option>
</select>
```

here's my JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.select2-multi').select2();
$('.select2-multi').select2().val({!! json_encode($company->maincategories()->allRelatedIds()) !!}).trigger('change');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you get your category data correctly to your view; Which seems to be an array from the code. You can **foreach** them inside your select element.

```
<select class="form-control select2-multi" name="company_main_cat[]" multiple="multiple" style="width: 50%" data-placeholder="select main category">
  @foreach($category as $category_single)
    <option value='{{$category_single->main_cat_id}}'>{{$category_single->main_cat_name}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: unfortunately, I think I didn't get the data correctly in my controller. Is my controller fine? what about my javascript? I'm really new in coding. thanks.

Comment: the array inside the name helped me thanks!  name="company_main_cat[]"